# Calculating resolutions for OpenLayers WMS layer missmatches GWC

Tags: openlayers, resolution, geowebcache

I need to use 512 sized tiles to display radar tiles from the NWS GWC, but after following the examples from OpenLayers, the resolutions do not line-up and I get the following error when requesting tiles:

`400: X,Y values for the tile index were calculated to be {2.228200080828475, 4.265270889325092} which had to be rounded to {2, 4} and exceeds the threshold of 10%. Perhaps the client is using the wrong origin ?`

I repurposed the OpenLayers example, https://4fu9ev.csb.app/ copied below. The first question is why does the code result in double the size tile requests, for example, even though I set `tileSize` to 512, it makes requests for 1024 tiles, and why does the NWS GWC not like the resolution calcuations?

I added some debug output to display the parameters of the broken tile requests. If you remove the tileGrid so it uses the default 256 tiles it loads the tiles correctly.

```
const nwsSource = new TileWMS({
  url: 'https://opengeo-dev.ncep.noaa.gov/geoserver/conus/conus_bref_qcd/ows',
  params: {LAYERS: 'conus_bref_qcd', TILED: true, VERSION: '1.1.1'},
  serverType: 'geoserver'
});
```

Here is the GetCapabilities request if that helps:
https://opengeo.ncep.noaa.gov/geoserver/conus/conus_bref_qcd/ows?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileGrid from 'ol/tilegrid/TileGrid.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import TileWMS from 'ol/source/TileWMS.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import {get as getProjection} from 'ol/proj.js';
import {getWidth} from 'ol/extent.js';

const tileSize = 512;

const projExtent = getProjection('EPSG:3857').getExtent();
const startResolution = getWidth(projExtent) / tileSize;
const resolutions = new Array(22);
for (let i = 0, ii = resolutions.length; i < ii; ++i) {
  resolutions[i] = startResolution / Math.pow(2, i);
}
const tileGrid = new TileGrid({
  extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
  resolutions: resolutions,
  tileSize: [tileSize, tileSize],
});

const nwsSource = new TileWMS({
  url: 'https://opengeo-dev.ncep.noaa.gov/geoserver/conus/conus_bref_qcd/ows',
  params: {LAYERS: 'conus_bref_qcd', TILED: true, VERSION: '1.1.1'},
  serverType: 'geoserver',
  tileGrid: tileGrid,
});

const layers = [
  new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
  }),
  new TileLayer({
    source: nwsSource,
  }),
];
const map = new Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-10997148, 4569099],
    zoom: 4,
  }),
});
const debug = document.getElementById('debug');
debug.innerHTML = `<p>Tile Size: ${tileSize}</p>`;
nwsSource.on('tileloaderror', function (event) {
  console.log(event);
  debug.innerHTML += `<pre>${event.tile.src_.replaceAll('&', '<br>&')}<pre>`;
});
```

Comment: How do you know that geowebcache is enabled?

Comment: I know first-hand that if `TILED=true` then it is routed to GWC.

Comment: That's not correct,  there are other requirements. see https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html

Comment: make sure you are using the resolutions in the capabilities document - I suspect you are off by one hence the 1024 instead of 512

Comment: oddly, I don't see the resolutions in the document, can you see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify a tile grid origin the top right of the extent to which you are limiting serving of tiles is assumes.  The correct value in this case seems to be the top right of the projection extent (which is normal for global projections).

```
const tileGrid = new TileGrid({
  extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
  origin: getTopRight(projExtent),
  resolutions: resolutions,
  tileSize: [tileSize, tileSize],
});
```

Comment: That's a big help, but now it is saying it doesn't support 1024 tiles (as expected) --any idea why it's doubling the tile size in the request?

Comment: Your codesandbox works for me when I make that change, so most likely your device pixel ratio being used.  To prevent that either specify `hidpi: false` in the source options or `pixelRatio: 1` in the map options.

Comment: that was it...thank you thank you thank you